# Facebook app post

Tags: facebook

Please suggest to me I'm a new developer, and I have application post to my page and I post them every 1 hour with 5 posts, but facebook delete all my posts and my application I think facebook look my application like spam, so i need to know how many I can post to a new fan page per day and  how many period to post ?

sorry for my English.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting this to your users walls using publish_stream?

It is not well documented, but [http://fbdevwiki.com/](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Graph%3aPost#Notes.2FBugs.2FGotchas) says it is 25 posts per day now. It is consistent with what I've seen while testing.

The [publish stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) permission documentation also says "However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model."